# Qualification title for French "diplôme d'ingénieur"

Tags: abbreviations, french

My Google-fu has maybe failed me, but I couldn't find an authoritative source about the correct English qualification title for a French *diplôme d'ingénieur*.

Some sources say the title is M.Sc., others MEng., so I'm not sure which one suits it best.

Comment: It will vary from country to country, and in the U.S.A, where there is not national educational certification, it varies from school to school.

Comment: If I'm particularly interested about its usage in the UK, should I add it to the question then?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about how a domain-specific *foreign* usage relates to "similar" domain-specific *English* qualifications.

Comment: The term means in US education parlance: an engineering degree, as a generic thing. https://www.cti-commission.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/mou_aacrao-cti.pdf Then, you add stuff: diplôme d'ingénieur en [something]

Comment: I would think that the natural thing to do would be to try to find a comparable degree and say 'equivalent to'. That is, there is no actual translation of the degree label, just similar qualifications. In that case, you might get a more accurate answer over at [academics.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most generic term which would be understood in the majority of English speaking academic circles is a *Masters of Engineering*. The names can vary enormously depending on the institution offering the degree, but most people should understand *Masters of Engineering*. Some examples:

- [Harvard](https://www.seas.harvard.edu/academics/graduate)

  > Engineering Sciences: Electrical Engineering (S.M., M.E., Ph.D.)
  >
  > Engineering Sciences: Environmental Science and Engineering (S.M.,
  >   M.E., Ph.D) Engineering Sciences: Mechanical Engineering (including a
  >
  > Materials Science track) (M.S.E.)
- [MIT](http://cee.mit.edu/master-of-engineering)

  > The Department of Civil and Environmental Engineering's Master of Engineering (M.Eng.) is a nine-month program that provides a practice-oriented education.
- [Oxford](http://www.eng.ox.ac.uk/admissions/postgraduate/graduate-research-degrees)

  > The advanced research degrees which may be awarded to graduate students in the Department are Master of Science (MSc) by research and Doctor of Philosophy (DPhil):
- [Cambridge](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/postgraduate/prospective-students/masters-courses/)

  > MPhil in Energy Technologies
  >
  > MPhil in Engineering for Sustainable Development
  >
  > MPhil in Industrial Systems, Manufacturing and Management
  >
  > MPhil in Nuclear Energy
  >
  > MRes Photonics Systems Development
  >
  > MRes in Ultra Precision
  >
  > MSt Construction Engineering

Comment: Other British universities (eg [Surrey](http://www.surrey.ac.uk/undergraduate/civil-engineering)) actually have an MEng.

Comment: *Engineering degree* seems more generic, but maybe you could explain why it's wrong.

Comment: @StuartF I would understand that to mean an undergraduate degree. At least in my experience, "degree" with no qualifications is usually used for the first, undergraduate degree. The French diplôme d'ingénieur is a much more specific, and post graduate thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipl%C3%B4me_d'Ing%C3%A9nieur.

Answer (score 3):

I usually present my *Diplome d'Ingenieur* as a MSc in Engineering, on the basis that MEng programmes in the UK are shorter and considered slightly less thorough than BSc+MSc programmes. In fact, MEng is an undergraduate degree, whilst the French DI is closer to a French MSc and would be a postgraduate degree.

However, [some universities also offer MSc in Engineering programmes in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Engineering#France), which are distinct from the *DI*. I personally do not care to make a distinction between University and *Grandes Ecoles*, but if the distinction is usually recognised in a specific industry (i.e. if the industry specifically wants certified engineers), one would be better off explicitly stating that their degree is a certified *Diplome d'Ingenieur*.